# Is their a theoretical minimal amout of energy to keep some information?

Tags: energy, information

The goal here is to keep a bit of information $b$ at the temperature $T$ during a time $\delta t$.

I don't know if this question makes a lot of sense, considering the diversity of ways to encode information.

But is there a way to generalize all this techniques in term of state and particle?

Then could we obtain a lower bound on the energy we need to spend to keep this information unaltered.

It's a question very open, so don't hesitate to reformulate the problem in a way understandable for you.
And I hope it's not a off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum amount of energy required to erase 1 bit of information is $kT\log{2}$ ([Landauer limit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle))

If an object is isolated, then it never reaches thermal equilibrium, and no energy is required to support such state (and the information stored in it). In practice, however, [quantum decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence) takes place, and the system loses all information about its initial state. Energy required to keep state coherent may vary for different cases.

Comment: Is there no any minimal amount required among all cases?